# Why does executing SQL against Hive table using SQLContext in application fail (but the same query in spark-shell works fine)?

Tags: java, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I am using Spark **1.6**.

I am trying to connect to a table in my spark-sql java code by :

```
JavaSparkContext js = new JavaSparkContext();
SQLContext sc = new SQLContext(js); 

DataFrame mainFile = sc.sql("Select * from db.table");
```

It gives me a table not found exception.

But when I do that in spark-shell using scala, it works fine.The table gets accessed and I can print out the data also.

Any inputs on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark-shell provides HiveContext. If you want to use HiveContext in Java code then add dependency for that in your application and then use in java program. Please refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```